# How one can save state of a game and retrieve back?

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle, savestate

I'm unsure on how to save the game state of my game that I'm developing. Whenever back boutton is pressed I need to save the actual state (such game board with all placed tokens, etc...). All of these are lost whenever the back button is pressed. Should I save a instance, object containing all the game informations? How? Or should I save all the relative informationsin an SQLite data base? And retrieve them when the activity is launched?

I have created two buttons: one for New game and the other that resumes  a saved game. For now only the one that launches new game works.

What is the best practice to achieve this? Please provide some exemple. Thanks

PS: I Still a learner so please bear with me.

Comment: It might make more sense to just save the game state in some sort of JSON file on the internal storage (in your data folder). I don't think GameState is typically *relational*.

Comment: If the [Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) is supported on Android (I have no reason to believe it isn’t), that would be the perfect place to store the game state.

Comment: Do you mean SharedPreference ? @AJNeufeld

Comment: Nope. I’m referring to the standard JDK Preferences class, which is supposed to be implemented on every platform.  (On Windows, the preferences are stored in the Windows Registry.  Other platforms store the preferences in flat files, or databases, etc.  But how they are stored isn’t important.).

Comment: I see that. Thanks. So should I use SharedPreference to store state for e.g: wheb user press on Back Button and retrieves when they returns back to the game party?